# rails test unit stubbing and then calling the method via try

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test and for some reason whenever i call the method I am stubbing from a try block it does not return the stubbed results. Is there something special i need to configure in order to make this work? I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3

```
squirtle.stubs(:bubbles?).returns(true)
puts squirtle.bubbles?
 => true
puts squirtle.try(:bubbles?)
 => false
```

Thanks!

Comment: works as expected in 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.8, have you tried `send`?

Comment: yeah unfortunately i am stuck on ruby 1.8.7 and no send won't work. Send basically allows you to call private methods where as try doesn't error out if there is a nil object

Comment: What stub/mock framework are you using in Rails 2.3?

Comment: i am using mocha to stub the method calls